# Property does not exist on type 'Object' when it is what I really want - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am returning an object containing only one field, of which I would prefer to return rather than the whole object, yet I am being met with the erorr:

> Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object'

Is there any way I can get around this, or am I stuck returning `res` wholly?

**UPDATE**
If I console.log() out what I get back, I am left with the following:

console.log(res):

*Note: Tokens will be different on purpose due to how I have set up the code*

Comment: because `token` is not there, try using console or debugger

Comment: Apologies, it does produce what I require when I console.log it out. I will update my question with screenshots - @AkhilAravind - see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should specify the structure of the response object

Either use

`this.http.post<{token:string}>(this.apiBaseUrl + '/auth', body)`

or

`this.http.post<any>(this.apiBaseUrl + '/auth', body)`

Comment: Ahh cracking! That worked a treat. I guess it needed to know what it was bringing back for it to work.